# Create each row for each cell

Tags: excel

I want to have each row for each split cell. So let's say I have an Excel with two columns, country and cities:

```
Country        Cities

UK             London
               Bristol


USA            New York
               Chicago
```

Against each cell of the first column I have multiple cells in the second column. What I want is to have:

```
UK      London
UK      Bristol
USA     New york
USA     Chicago
```

so I could import that into a different tool.

Comment: make a third column where [cell c2]  =IF(A2="",C1,A2)

Answer (score 0):

Filter to select blank cells in the `Cities` column and delete these. Then select the `Country` column and HOME > Editing, Find & Select, Go To Special..., check Blanks (only), <kbd>=</kbd>, <kbd>Up</kbd>, <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Enter</kbd>. Delete any unnecessary rows/cells at the bottom.